Converting Official json schema to Spark json
I currently have a string representing an official JSON Schema (https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring) and I want to transform it into a StructType instance using
DataType.fromJson(myJson).asInstanceOf[StructType]

The challenge is that the fromJson method only accepts JSON in a Spark-specific format. I'm searching for a solution, potentially a third-party library, that can take a JSON string in the official JSON Schema format and convert it into Spark's JSON format.
Additionally, it's important for my requirements that the JSON remains a string. I want to avoid writing or saving the JSON to my file system e.g using spark.read.json(..).
